# What does the knex.js method `table.increments()` do when no args are passed in?

Tags: javascript, default-value, knex.js

I'm working on a codebase and I see a few migrations that invoke `table.increments()` when restoring a table inside a `knex.schema.createTable()` call. Looking at [the documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-increments) for this method, it appears to add an auto-incrementing column with the given name. However, in my case it's being called without any arguments. Is there some kind of default parameter that's being used for `name`? Or is `table.increments()` just not doing anything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the name `id` for the column by default if none is specified. [Here's the code where this behavior is defined](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/9aa7085b052938dc5252d10b2b418a475637eda5/lib/schema/columncompiler.js#L37).

It's unfortunate this is not documented, perhaps an issue could be opened up in their GitHub page to bring this to the attention of the knex team.